# How to prevent Redshift from logging a query

Tags: logging, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to prevent Redshift from logging a query?

Redshift will not allow me to truncate the STL_QUERY table.

truncate STL_QUERY

You would think that there would be a "NOLOG" keyword for a query.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to clear or redact the query log.